# How to force chrome to load a local Javascript file instead of a remote one?

Tags: google-chrome, fiddler

I know how to do this with Fiddler (define rules and etc.) but my problem is that Fiddler crashes usually, is there any other stable method?

Comment: Are the crashes reproducible? Is there any stack trace?

Comment: It is reproducible (after two hours), it says buffer overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Fiddler for this all the time quite successfully.

Chrome's F12 dev tools let you edit the JS source but it's not used when you refresh the page.

The issue you face is addressed [here](https://aarontgrogg.com/blog/2015/03/24/how-to-replace-remote-files-with-local-files-when-debugging/). Looks like you need a local webserver (like mongoose) and the [Redirect plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-redirect/jmhdebkkippcccflcoddckhjjfgnfhnp).